# Второй StatusBar в проводнике [Windows 10]

Tags: windows, windows-10

После установки виндовс ставил все программы подряд по своему списку, сразу не обратил внимание, что появился еще один статус бар в проводнике, к тому же на русском (язык у windows в дальнейшем был изменен на английский, а текст в статус баре остался на русском).
Так же статус бар с белым оформлением, когда в windows включена темная тема.

[image: Description]

Вопрос: как найти программу которая его добавила и отключить.
Список установленных программ:

```
4K Video Downloader 4.12  
7-Zip 19.00 (x64)  
Adobe Flash Player 32 PPAPI  
AIDA64 5.97.4600 Final  
AIMP  
App Installer  
ASIO4ALL  
Audacity 2.4.2  
AutoHotkey 1.1.30.00  
Bandicam  
Bandisoft MPEG-1 Decoder  
CCleaner  
Classic Shell  
ColorMania 11.0  
CurseForge  
Dropbox  
English (United States) Local Experience Pack  
Factorio [v1.0]  
FileZilla Client 3.51.0  
FL Studio 20  
FL Studio ASIO  
Game Redistributables version 1.1.1.1  
Git version 2.28.0  
Google Chrome  
HeidiSQL 11.1.0.6116  
HxD Hex Editor 2.4  
Java 8 Update 271 (64-bit)  
LogMeIn Hamachi  
Mem Reduct  
Microsoft Office профессиональный плюс 2016  
Microsoft Store  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable - x64 8.0.61000  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable - x86 8.0.61001  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x64 10.0.40219  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable - x86 10.0.40219  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.61030  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.61030  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.40664  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) - 12.0.40664  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.20.27607  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.20.27607  
Microsoft Visual Studio Code (User)  
Moo0 Системный монитор 1.83  
Movavi Video Suite 18.1.0  
MTA:SA v1.5.7  
NVIDIA Control Panel  
NVIDIA Графический драйвер 432.00  
Overwolf  
paint.net  
Picasa 3  
qBittorrent 4.2.5  
QTTabBar ver 1043  
Radmin VPN 1.1.8  
Resource Hacker Version 4.7.34  
Restorator 2009  
RivaTuner Statistics Server 7.2.0  
Screenpic 0.15.2  
Skype, версия 8.66  
Sound Lock  
Store Experience Host  
TeamViewer  
Twitch  
Viber  
Windscribe  
Xbox Identity Provider  
Пакет локализованного интерфейса на русском
```

**Виновник торжества: Classic Shell. Думал о нем в последнюю очередь.**

Comment: Отключать по очереди все программы, пока не пропадет статус бар. Та, на которой пропадет - виновная. Приложите список программ в вопрос, возможно, это поможет.

Comment: "Classic Shell" наверное?

Comment: И в правду.. О нем я думал в последнюю очередь. Спасибо.